USB POS Printer loses connection suddenly
I have a Windows 10 PC which is up to date, connected to a POS printer by mean of USB cable.
The problem I am having is that I am printing normally in it, using Windows spool, and it works, until suddenly printer loses connection, causing the print queue to stay for ever.
To recover control, I need the printer to turn off and on, or reboot the PC. After that, all pending jobs are printed normally.
Driver is not the problem, I have uninstalled and install the driver again. I have cleaned the printing spool, I have changed cable, I have changed printer, and problem is not solved. The only thing I have not done is to reinstall Windows or changed the PC because these are the most complicated thing to do.
What else can I try?
Thanks
Jaime

Did you try a different USB port on the computer?

There are a few things that could cause the issue.

Though USB is less susceptible to noise than WiFi, electrical glitches, particularly if the the printer and PC are plugged into different AC outlets, could break the connection. Is the POS in an electrically noisy environment, such as an area where arc-welding is done? If so, connect the printer and PC to the same, RFI-suppressor power strip, and unplug other devices from them. Perhaps printer and PC need to be on an uninterruptible power supply (UPS).
If possible, off-hours, try booting the PC from USB (e.g., Ubuntu Live or Hirens BootCD PE, and run a few print jobs over some period of time. If that works consistently, then the issue might be in Windows or the drive containing the OS.

